# Ignoring method in my object with HotChocolate GraphQL

Tags: c#, .net, graphql, hotchocolate

I have a class that I expose with Hotchocolate and GraphQL.

In this class I have some properties and a public method with the following signature :

`public Expression<Func<Parcelle, bool>> ToLambdaExpression()`

By default, Hot Chocolate picks up the public method and exposes them as fields in the graphql schema. I managed to ignore them with an object type extension like this :

```
protected override void Configure(IObjectTypeDescriptor<ParcelSelectionCriteriaExpression> descriptor)
    {
        descriptor.Ignore(t => t.TokenizeExpression());
    }
```

And it worked most of the time for methods returning simple types. But when I try to do that for my `ToLambdaExpression` method, I get an error during schema validation.

```
public class ParcelSelectionCriteriaExtension : ObjectTypeExtension<ParcelSelectionCriteria>
{
    protected override void Configure(IObjectTypeDescriptor<ParcelSelectionCriteria> descriptor)
    {
        descriptor.Ignore(t => t.ToLambdaExpression());
    }
}
```

```
 HotChocolate.SchemaException: For more details look at the `Errors` property.

      1. Unable to infer or resolve a schema type from the type reference `Expression (Input)`.
```

If I comment the `ToLambdaExpression` method, everything works. It looks like even if I ignore the field, it tries to resolve its type and since it's an `Expression<Func<Parcelle, bool>>` it can't figure out how to type it.

Is there a way to make HotChocolate completely ignore this method without having to create a DTO ?

Answer (score 0):

For me it is more natural (semantically) to use "Type definition" but not [type extension](https://chillicream.com/docs/hotchocolate/v13/defining-a-schema/extending-types) here.
In that case, the following approach should work:

```
public class ParcelSelectionCriteria
{
 public Expression<Func<Parcelle, bool>> ToLambdaExpression() 
 {
  throw new NotImplementedException();
 }
}

public class ParcelSelectionCriteriaType : ObjectType<ParcelSelectionCriteria>
{
 protected override void Configure(IObjectTypeDescriptor<ParcelSelectionCriteria> descriptor)
 {
  descriptor.Field(t => t.ToLambdaExpression()).Ignore();
 }
}
```

But, anyway, the approach with the type extension is supposed to work as well. Otherwise, I guess, it is a [bug](https://github.com/ChilliCream/graphql-platform/issues/6802).